# Photo printed on tshirts?

Tags: software, digital, printing, fashion

I didn't know if there was a place to go to, on stackexchange for this question, but since it deals with photography, I feel like I would ask here.

I have a few photos with amazing landscapes and have turned them into shirt ideas, custom for myself. I haven't been able to find a place that prints all the way at the bottom of a shirt, which to me is a deal breaker. Shirts look awesome when photos stretch totally over it. Has anyone had any experience with this type of custom shirts?

I'm trying to make something like this: http://www.designbyhumans.com/shop/men/altitude-sickness-skull-astronaut-abstract-shirt/6510/

Or like this: http://www.designbyhumans.com/shop/men/no-fear-swinging-over-the-ocean-cliffs-t-shirt/8523/

Comment: Never done this but these links seem to have the option accepting your own design. I am sure they take a cut but paying for printing to be done anywhere else will cost too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for something similar, and found this:

http://www.jakprints.com/all-over-shirt-printing/

I haven't used them, so I can't recommend them.  But they do look interesting.

When you are looking, use the term "all over printing".

Answer (score 0):

you can also try  "T Shirt transfer paper" and use any inkjet printer, the image printed would be the mirror of the image (on paper) and use Iron to transfer the photo.

This is not exactly as  All over printing but is less expensive and quick, can do it @ home.

http://www.desmat.com/product1.php?pcode=2&scode=6